# Python button double press

Tags: pi-3, python-3

I'm about to start building a wireless custom doorbell system using pigpio. It is a three piece system that I will be making. The front doorbell which will communicate via two scripts to two different RPIs. This is done because the chime systems have a display value of two items I want from a visual perspective. One will play an MP3 and the other the clip MP4. In both scripts I need to identify a specific MP3 or MP4 for a button press. For example if I press the button on my front door RPI it should run MP3-1 and MP4-1 and if I press it again MP3-2 and MP4-2. I can run multiple using a random number generator which is not difficult

```
randint(0,9)
if number == 1 etc.
```

Assign a value to each mp3 or mp4 and if the number is equal to that number then that file will play. I am trying to run a specific file for the first press and a separate file for the second press on the same button. I am not sure how to count the presses and perform a new action with each one. If I can get the system to recognize press 2 then I should be able to run it. I appreciate any insight.

Comment: How about setting 'press = 0' then incrementing press each time the doorbell is pressed 'press += 1'. You may want to reset to 0 when 2 is reached or maybe after some delay?

Comment: ok so I could do press=0 the while true if button is pressed then press+=1 which would increment the press then I could if press =1 play this file and if 2 this file and if 3 this file etc. That would work I think. Ill try that

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a boolean variable named "chimeOne", defaulted to False, paired to a datetime object "dt" containing the time the button was pressed. If the button is pressed, `chimeOne = True`. If within 30 seconds it is pressed again, (determined by `if chimeOne == True: #Add an exception if the time elapsed between now and dt is more than 30 seconds`), play the second mp3. However, if 30 seconds (or any other interval you can think of) elapses `and chimeOne:` then `chimeOne = False`.

The advantage of this is that you won't have a false alarm, if a visitor pressed once, and a couple days later, another visitor presses the doorbell.

Here's a skeleton script showing the basic outline of the procedure:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

"""
When a button is pressed, call the procedure onDoorbell().
Make sure to add code to play the MP3/MP4
"""


timeStamp = None
chimeOne = False

def retTimestamp(type): #Handles date/time settings

 data = re.compile('\w+').findall(text) 

 return data 

def onDoorbell: #Handles doorbell push

 if chimeOne:

  data = retTimestamp()

  oldHour   = int(data[1])
  oldMinute = int(data[2])

  global timeStamp, chimeOne

  timeStamp = datetime.now().strftime('%H %M')

  data = retTimestamp()

  nowHour = data[1]
  nowMinute = data[2]

  if nowHour == oldHour and nowMinute == oldMinute:
   """
   Play the second MP3 if the second push was within
   the same minute of the first.
   """
  else:
   """
   Play the second MP3; the second push happened
   too late.
   """

  chimeOne = False

 else:

  global timeStamp, chimeOne

  timeStamp = datetime.now().strftime('%H %M')
  chimeOne = True

  """
  Play the first MP3.
  """
```

Comment: That's actually really interesting because using the hour and minute variables would like you said allow to ensure the same chime does not repeat. I would need to use elif since this will be about 15 mp3s so I would have to add a loop on it so if the pushes were exceeded it would start back at the first MP3 but that's something to look at. Once I get it running ill need to modify